# How to loop though a jQuery result set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn jquery and I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to deal with a set of jquery results. Let's say I have some html like:

```
<div class="divClass">
  <p class="pClass1">1</p>
  <p class="pClass2">Some text.</p>
</div>
<div class="divClass">
  <p class="pClass1">2</p>
  <p class="pClass2">Some text.</p>
</div>
<div class="divClass">
  <p class="pClass1">3</p>
  <p class="pClass2">Some text.</p>
</div>
```

I want to loop through the div's with a class of "divClass", get the value contained in the child p with a class of "pClass1". Getting the set of div's with a class of "divClass" is easy with something like:

```
divs = $(".divClass");
```

But I'm not sure how to loop through "divs" and find the "pClass1" child, then get its value. Any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `each` method, and then, look for the '.pClass' elements, in the context of `this`, which is the currently div being iterated:

```
var divs = $(".divClass");

divs.each(function () {
  alert($('p.pClass1', this).text());
});
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/iforu).

Comment: This answers my question. Can you point me to where the second parameter of this statement is documented?

$('p.pClass1', this)

That is what I could not figure out how to do and could not find in the documentation. I still cannot find it after you've shown me how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`each`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each) method:

```
$(".divClass").each(function() {

});
```

Comment: and `this` refers to the element each iteration

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways.

For your specific scenario, I would try something like this:

```
$(".divClass .pClass1").each(function() {
    // Do whatever
});
```

If you wanted to do something with the div tags and the p tags, you could try the **find** method:

```
$(".divClass").each(function() {
   var p1Tags = $(this).find(".pClass1");
});
```